# Why datamapper always round a default decimal to a integer

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I use Ruby sinatra with datamapper.
In my model I have a decimal property

```
property :sim_update_interval, Decimal, :precision=>10, :scale=>2 , :default=>0.9
```

The problem is: 
Everytime  I creates a new instance of the model, the default value of :sim_update_interval is never 0.9, but 1.0

```
puts instance.sim_update_interval 
#=> 0.1E1
```

I tried to change the default value to 0.2, the output became 0.0
It seems that datamapper always round the default value to an integer. I am so confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that rake db:migrate do not modify existing columns when there is data(rows) in the table. I wiped the table and do rake db:migrate, everything is ok now.